# json_decode not working within php script run as cron job

Tags: php, mysql, json, cron

I have a php script that calls a JSON array from a URL and parses it, and saves it to a MySQL database.

If I run the php script from my browser then everything works.

The url is called, the JSON array received, and the database updated with all data retrieved from the URL.

I also call this same script from a cron job - but when the cron job runs, the data written to the MySQL database is blank.

Everything seems to work except the decoding of the JSON response.

This is the code in my php script:

```
$json_string = 'url_to_be_called';
$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$obj = json_decode($jsondata, true);

$BTC_AMP = $obj['BTC_AMP']['last'];
```

The code all works perfectly when called from a browser.

Either json_decode or file_get_contents don't seem to work correctly when called from the cron job.

Comment: show the cron entry, any script it invokes, where is located this .php, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code, you are expecting a JSON formatted string on your request body. You need to ensure your Cron job setup to send the body as part of the request.

Comment: How would I do this? And why would that be different when running as a cron job vs running directly from the browser?

Comment: If you are trying to Post to a URL then a Cron Job is not what you need, Try Using a Curl, or a Cron job that calls a script that does a Curl to the page with the Post body